# How to create a reference to the base service methods?

Tags: c#, wcf, inheritance

I have service classes hierarchy like this:

base service:

```
[ServiceContract()]
public interface IServiceBase
{
    [OperationContract]
    void BaseMethod();
}

public class ServiceBase : IServiceBase
{
    public void BaseMethod()
    {}
}
```

service A:

```
[ServiceContract()]
public interface IServiceA : IServiceBase
{}

public class ServiceA : ServiceBase, IServiceA
{}
```

service B:

```
[ServiceContract()]
public interface IServiceB : IServiceBase
{}

public class ServiceB : ServiceBase, IServiceB
{}
```

On the client side I create two proxy classes for ServiceA and ServiceB through Visual Studio's "Add service reference" tool:

```
ProxyA proxyServiceA;
ProxyB proxyServiceB;
```

**These are references on TWO DIFFERENT SERVICES** (although with a base class on the server side).

I want to call methods from the BaseService through these proxies in identical way. For example I want to pass these proxies as a parameter to a method and call its BaseService method, like this:

```
// somewhere on the client side
WorkMethod(proxyServiceA);
WorkMethod(proxyServiceB);

// Something like this, BUT I DON'T REALLY KNOW WHAT TYPE OF PARAMETER TO USE
void WorkMethod(ProxyBase proxyBase)
{
    proxyBase.BaseMethod();
}
```

But how to do it, what type of parameter to use (remember that these proxies are different classes without BaseService common ancestor)?

In another words, on the server side it is known that ServiceA and ServiceB has a common ancestor and it is possible to call a base method, but how to do it on the client side?

**Is it possible to obtain some class on the client that is recognized as a base class for these two proxies?** (except System.ServiceModel.ClientBase of course)

Comment: The problem is almost the same as in [this case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422567/wcf-service-inheritance) - creating a base proxy that implements the base service.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **ServiceKnownTypeAttribute** Class. The `KnownType` attribute allows you to designate acceptable subclasses for the data contract (Your base service). This sample show how it use. Whithout `KnowType` you will always get exception like

> CommunicationException was unhandled

```
[DataContract] 
[KnownType( typeof( Student ) )]
[KnownType( typeof(Teacher) )]
public abstract class BaseService
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Code { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
[DataContract]  
public class Student : BaseService
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
    }
[DataContract]
public class Teacher : BaseService
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int TeacherId { get; set; }
    }
```

[Here is MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute.aspx)

Comment: I added more clarity to my question with code samples. I think the known types is not the key or only a part of the key. I don't understand the part of my code where I have to call WorkMethod - how can I pass any of these proxies (proxyServiceA or proxyServiceB) to the WorkMethod method and call BaseMethod? The known types aren't enough I think.

Comment: The known types concept is related to data contracts. There are no data contracts in my question. My question is about sharing the base implementation of the base interface and trying to use this base functionality on the client. Sorry, I think your answer is not relative.